# Alternatives to GlobalWindow for rolling aggregation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm wondering if Flink is suitable for the following use case. Let's say I have a stream of measurements (device_id, value), e.g.

(1, 10.2), (2, 3.4), (3, 9.1), (1, 7.0), (3, 6.3), (5, 17.8)

And I want to report every minute the latest value for any device_id has been seen so far.

Given the data:

```
data:  (1, 10.2), (2, 3.4), (3, 9.1), (1, 7.0), (3, 6.3), (5, 17.8)

time: 0 ----------------- 1min -------------- 2min ------------------ 3min
```

I'd like to have a result:

1: { (1, 10.2), (2, 3.4) }

2: { (1, 7.0), (2, 3.4), (3, 9.1) }

3: { (1, 7.0), (2, 3.4), (3, 6.3), (5, 17.8) }

I came up with the implementation that includes

```
.windowAll(GlobalWindows.create()).trigger(CountTrigger.of(1)).apply( ... )
```

but it doesn't look good (memory wise) on a large dataset. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any expiration policy at all? the way that you've mentioned will (in the case of diverse device_id) will be a problem, but not just memory related one! consider the cost and lag of the state serialization! in your streaming application.

Comment: @RezaSamei I do, but not "time based" meaning that device can send a special event (device_id, -1). Such event indicates that I do not need to maintain anymore the value for this device_id. But, I agree that cost of serialization is also a concern, hence the question in the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider something more like this as the starting point:

```
public class StreamingJob {
  private static final TimeUnit windowTimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
  private static final long windowLength = 10;

  private static long getNearestRightBoundaryFor(Long timestamp, Long duration, TimeUnit unit){
    Long durationEpoch = unit.toMillis(duration);
    Long quotient = timestamp / durationEpoch;
    return (quotient + 1) * durationEpoch - 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.fromElements(
            Tuple3.of(1000L, 1L, 3.8f), Tuple3.of(2003L, 2L, 82.3f), Tuple3.of(3006L, 1L, 4.2f), // 0 - 09
            Tuple3.of(11120L, 2L, 10f), Tuple3.of(12140L, 2L, 7.15f), Tuple3.of(13150L, 3L, 3.33f), // 10 - 19
            Tuple3.of(21200L, 2L, 1.09f), Tuple3.of(22270L, 1L, 2.22f), Tuple3.of(23280L, 2L, 3.8f), // 20 - 29
            Tuple3.of(31310L, 3L, 3.12f), Tuple3.of(32330L, 2L, 9.2f), Tuple3.of(33390L, 1L, 4.0f) // 30 - 39
    )
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
            new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<Tuple3<Long,Long,Float>>() {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(Tuple3<Long, Long, Float> lastElement, long extractedTimestamp) {
                    return new Watermark(extractedTimestamp);
                }

                @Override
                public long extractTimestamp(Tuple3<Long, Long, Float> element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
                    return element.f0;
                }
            })
    .keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple3<Long,Long,Float>, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long getKey(Tuple3<Long, Long, Float> value) throws Exception {
            return value.f1;
        }
    })
    .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<Long, Tuple3<Long,Long,Float>, Tuple4<Long, Long, Long, Float>>() {
        private ValueState<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>> state;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) {
            ValueStateDescriptor<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                    "state",
                    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>>() {
                    }));

            state = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(Tuple3<Long, Long, Float> value, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple4<Long, Long, Long, Float>> out) throws Exception {
            Tuple3<Long, Long, Float> currentValue = state.value();
            if (currentValue == null) {
                Long ts = getNearestRightBoundaryFor(value.f0, windowLength, windowTimeUnit);
                ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ts);
                state.update(value);
            }
            else if (value.f0 > currentValue.f0) { // ignore out-of-order events
                state.update(value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Tuple4<Long, Long, Long, Float>> out) throws IOException {
            Tuple3<Long, Long, Float> currentValue = state.value();
            out.collect(new Tuple4(timestamp, currentValue.f0, currentValue.f1, currentValue.f2));
            Long newTs = timestamp + windowTimeUnit.toMillis(windowLength);
            if (ctx.timerService().currentWatermark() < Long.MAX_VALUE) {
                ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(newTs);
            }
        }
    })
    .print();
    env.execute("Flink FTW!");
  }
}
```

Some things to point out:

I wouldn't recommend using Windows for this. With GlobalWindows it gets complicated to manage expiring state.

I've used an AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks rather than an AscendingTimestampExtractor. I've done this for three reasons: (1) once you switch to running in parallel it may be difficult to ensure that the events arrive in order; (2) AscendingTimestampExtractors generate watermarks periodically (by default, every 200msec of real time) and for the purposes of this example the app has consumed all of its input before the first watermark is generated; (3) a simple check in the processElement method is all that's needed to cope with out-of-order events. But you're probably better off with an AscendingTimestampExtractor in production, if the events are truly in order, or a BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor.

The output looks like this:

```
(9999,11120,2,10.0)
(19999,21200,2,1.09)
(19999,13150,3,3.33)
(29999,23280,2,3.8)
(29999,31310,3,3.12)
(39999,32330,2,9.2)
(39999,31310,3,3.12)
(9999,3006,1,4.2)
(19999,3006,1,4.2)
(29999,22270,1,2.22)
(39999,33390,1,4.0)
```

The reason why (11120,2,10.0) is triggered at 9999 is because it is the arrival of this event with timestamp 11120 that advances the watermark past 9999, causing that timer to fire. By the time the onTimer is called, the onElement has already been called.

The check in onTimer for ctx.timerService().currentWatermark() < Long.MAX_VALUE is so that this finite example won't run forever. If a streaming job reaches the end of its input, a final watermark with timestamp of Long.MAX_VALUE is injected to cause one last firing of any remaining timers. In that case we shouldn't create another timer.

Comment: Hey @david-anderson thank you for your answer. I came up with an implementation of what you suggested https://gist.github.com/napplebee/fc09e78292767100690e5176869afb34 Two things that I can't understand though. First, I can't fire timer indefinitely from onTimer(), otherwise execution never proceed to the next steps like .timeWindowAll(). Second, it seems like onTimer observes time after processElement. So when onTimer is fired for t0 the state already holds value that is saved by processElement fired on t1. fyi: I executed my job using standalone flink. Can you please comment on these two?